# Exam $9768$ of subject $ GRE Q1.$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, gre-exam

This is the question:[image]

Could anyone give me a hint on how can I solve it?

Comment: Try using the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: Yes. First or second main theorem of calculus or what it could be called in english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the [Leibniz´s rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to compute the derivative 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(x,t) \,  dt =f(x,v(x))\cdot \frac{dv}{dx}-f(x,u(x))\cdot \frac{du}{dx}+\int_{_{}^{u(x)}}^{v(x)} \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x} \, dt$$

with $u(x)=e, v(x)=x, f(x,t)=\log(t)$

In your case $f(x,t)$ does not depend on $x$. Thus $\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}=0$. And $\frac{du}{dx}=0$ as well.

Answer (score 3):

HINT :

let $G$ be a primitive of $g(t) = log(t)$
then $F(x) = G(x)-G(e)$

What is $F'$ ? Can you finish ?

Answer (score 2):

The integral $\int \log x\ dx$ is just $x\log x-x$. If you apply the upper and lower bounds in your case, the result is $(x \log x -x - e\log e +e)$ (with $e$ being the Euler's constant).

Now you just have to differentiate this w.r.t. $x$. This is easy and in the end you get $\log x$.

This is a step by step method required that you know the primitive of $\log x$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Leibniz Integral Rule
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)dt=f(h(x)).\frac{dh}{dx}-f(g(x)).\frac{dg}{dx}$$
Given $f(t)=\ln(t)$, $h(x)=x$, $g(x)=e$